# laravel translate number to month or how to make created_at get the value of month name?

Tags: php, json, laravel

i want to get the value name in created_at field

i have the code like this

```
public function index()
{
    $month = ['01','02','03','04'];
    // $month = ['january','february','march','april'];

    $user = [];
    foreach ($month as $key => $value) {
        $user[] = User::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m')"),$value)->count();
    }

    return view('AdmPelatihan.Dashboard.index')->with('month',json_encode($month))->with('user',json_encode($user));
}
```

i want make it like 01 = januari, dst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`whereMonth()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses) method of the query builder.

Your code can be simplified to:

```php
public function index()
{
    $months = ['01','02','03','04'];

    $users = [];
    foreach ($months as $month) {
        $users[] = User::whereMonth('created_at', $month)->count();
    }

    return view('AdmPelatihan.Dashboard.index')->with([
        'months' => json_encode($months),
        'users' => json_encode($users)
    ]);
}
```

To be clear, this would apply to these months in any year.

If you want the month names in your view, you could also do something like:

```php
public function index()
{
    ...

    $monthNames = collect($months)->transform(function ($month) {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2021-'.$month.'-01')->format('F');
    })->toArray();

    return view('AdmPelatihan.Dashboard.index')->with([
        'months' => json_encode($months),
        'monthNames' => json_encode($monthNames),
        'users' => json_encode($users)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: wow thats magic sir.
and how if i want to make the year is dinamicly in this year.
like date("Y")

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters